# javascript+php change url value

Tags: php, javascript, url, onchange

this is my first post and i hope to help you to understand my problem.i'm new to this programming language!so...

i have this select menu and this is the code

```
select name="select3" id="select3" value="" onChange="

var x=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;

var k=document.form3.chk_list_hidden.value;

if(this.selectedIndex!=0){

k=x;
document.location.replace(window.location.href='<? $uri=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; echo $uri.'&selected=';?>'+k); }"
```

it works!but the result is that
http://localhost/test.php?array[1]&array[2]&array[3]&selected=array[1]

if i select another value from select menu the result is http://localhost/test.php?array[1]&array[2]&array[3]&selected=array[1]&selected=array[2]

but i want to replace &selected=array[1] to  &selected=array[2]

i try anything and i search it but i can't find anything...:(

Comment: Please fix the source.  Can't read it.

Comment: Don't put huge blobs of code into an `onWhatever=""` attribute. put it into a seperate `<javascript>` section as a function and just call that function from the onWhatever. It'll make debugging far simpler and the code easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

try this On your last line

```
document.location.replace(window.location.href='<? if(strstr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '&selected', true)) { $uri=strstr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '&selected', true);} else { $uri=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}; echo $uri.'&selected=';?>'+k); }"
```